# Using (x,y) coordinates to get to a specific "village" (Python 3)

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I'm sorry for the title being unreleated to my question. Help me think of one, and I'll change it (if possible).

Here's what I want to do. I"ll try to keep it short and simple.

There are villages that randomly spawn in a coordinate grid, (0-9). Each village has a class, coordinates, and a random village name.

I have successfully figured out how to print the game board. I'm stuck on the player being able to input coordinates to view the village's details.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
def drawing_board():
board_x = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()
board_y = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()
total_list = [board_x]
for i in range(1,10):
    listy = []
    for e in range(0,9):
        if e == 0:
            listy.append(str(i))
        listy.append('.')
    total_list.append(listy)
return total_list
drawing = drawing_board()
villages = [['5','2'],['5','5'],['8','5']] #I would like these to be random 
                                      #and associated with specific villages.
                                      #(read below)
for i in villages:
    x = int(i[1])
    y = int(i[0])
    drawing[x][y] = 'X'

for i in drawing:
    print(i)
print()
print('What village do you want to view?')
```

This prints the game board. Then I was thinking about making a class that would look like this:

```
import random
class new_village():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Random name'
        x = random.randint(1,9)
        y = random.randint(1,9)
        self.coordinates = [x,y]
        tribe = random.randint(1,2)
        if tribe == 1:
            self.tribe = 'gauls'
        elif tribe == 2:
            self.tribe = 'teutons'

    def getTribe(self):
        print('It is tribe ' +self.tribe)

    def getCoords(self):
        print(str(self.coordinates[0])+','+str(self.coordinates[1]))
```

So now the part that I'm stuck on. 
How can I make it to where the player can input coordinates and view a village like this?

Comment: For example. Player sees an X at 5,5. The player enters "5 5" and it will tell the player everything about the village. (name, tribe, or whatever else i want to add.)

Comment: To get user input, use [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input). Generate the villages randomly by using [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.randint).

Comment: @timgeb - Python 3 I believe, as the title suggests.  I'll change the tag.

Comment: okay, overlooked that. there are a couple of issues with your code which make it difficult to implement a clean solution for your problem. I'll write something up.

Comment: Did you notice that two villages can spawn in the exact same location  the way your code is currently written?

Comment: @timegb - This isn't my code!  I think the OP is away for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code which prevent you from implementing a clean solution for your problem.

First of all, I'd make `board_x` and `board_y` actually contain integers instead of strings, since you are generating random integers in the `__init__` method of `new_village`.

```
>>> board_x = list(range(10))
>>> board_y = list(range(1,10))
>>> board_x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> board_y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In addition, I would create a list of all locations on the map where there is no village yet like this:

```
locations = [(x,y) for x in board_x for y in board_y]
```

Now the critical problem with your code for the class is that two villages can spawn in the *exact same location*. When this happens and the user inputs coordinates, how would you know which values should be printed? To prevent this, you could pass your `locations` to the `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, locations):
    # sanity check: is the board full?
    if not locations:
        print('board is full!')
        raise ValueError

    # choose random location on the board as coordinates, then delete it from the global list of locations
    self.coordinates = random.choice(locations)
    del locations[locations.index(self.coordinates)]

    # choose name and tribe 
    self.name = 'Random name'
    self.tribe = random.choice(('gauls', 'teutons'))
```

Since you already have a class for your villages, your list `villages` should actually contain instances of this class, i.e. instead of

```
villages = [['5','2'],['5','5'],['8','5']]
```

you can issue

```
villages = [new_village(locations) for i in range(n)]
```

where `n` is the number of villages you want.
Now, to make further lookups easy, I suggest creating a dictionary which maps locations on your board to village instances:

```
villdict = {vill.coordinates:vill for vill in villages}
```

Finally, it is now easy to process user input and print the values for a village at the input-locations.

```
>>> inp = tuple(int(x) for x in input('input x,y: ').split(','))
input x,y: 5,4
>>> inp
(5, 4)
```

You can now issue:

```
if inp in villdict:
    chosen = villdict[inp]
    print(chosen.name)
    print(chosen.tribe)
else:
    print('this spot on the map has no village')
```

Comment: +1 - Agree with using `dict`.  Basically what I told the OP to do in my comment stream.

Comment: Alright, I know that I'm not supposed to give comments just to say thanks, but I'm impressed with everyone who put their time into answering my question. But I found that yours was the easiest for me to follow, and it was exactly what I was wanting, along with future things that I wanted to add.

Comment: @KyleMe another thing: If you want `villdict` to have a nice output when you print it, implement a custom `__repr__` method for `new_village`.

Comment: @KyleMe I updated my post, there was a logical error regarding the locations a village could spawn in. Please have a look at the updated post.

Comment: @timgeb Funny you should mention that, I was literally just typing in the comment section that the method for checking if the board was full or not didn't work. It had turned out that you had fixed it already. 
Very nice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) to accept a string from the user.  As you'll have two co-ordinates to punch in, perhaps call this twice.  Once you get the strings, cast the locations to integer via `int()`.

If you want to generate random locations, you can use [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.randrange).  The syntax for `random.randrange()` is like so:

```
num = random.randrange(start, stop) #OR
num = random.randrange(start, stop, step)
```

This will randomly generate a number from `start` to `stop` excluding `stop` itself.  This is pretty much the same as with `range()`.  The first method assumes a step size of 1, while the second method you can specify an optional third parameter which specifies the step size of your random integer generation.  For example, if `start = 2`, `stop = 12` and `step = 2`, this would randomly generate a integer from the set of `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the part that is stumping me is I'm not sure how I could make the village show up just given the coordinates.
Like how would I coordinate "Village wondersome" with coordinates 5,5?

Comment: OK, I think I get it.  So if I were to input co-ordinates `[5,5]`, you would want the output to display information about that village at that co-ordinate?  In that case, use a dictionary where the keys would be `(x,y)` tuples and the output would be a village associated with that particular location.  I would change the `__init__` method to customize the name of the village.

Comment: I'm sorry =p. I have trouble trying to explain it. 
I made a class and when something is passed through the class, it now has coordinates. I'm having trouble trying to display these coordinates as an "X" on the grid. I'm going to try to play around with it for a little bit longer. I appreciate the help, though. Thanks :)

Comment: What happens when there isn't a village occupied at the spot?  Would it be displayed as an `O`? You're welcome btw!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking your `getTribe()` function should `return` the tribe not `print` it. However, the main thing which I would do is to create a separate function to test whether a set of supplied coordinates are the same as that of the village. Lets say, you changed your class like so:

```
import random

class new_village():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Random name'
        x = random.randint(1,9)
        y = random.randint(1,9)
        self.coordinates = [x,y]
        tribe = random.randint(1,2)
        if tribe == 1:
            self.tribe = 'gauls'
        elif tribe == 2:
            self.tribe = 'teutons'

    def getTribe(self): return self.tribe

    def getCoords(self): return self.coordinates

    def areCoordinates(self, x, y):
        if [x, y] == self.coordinates: return True
        else: return False

    def printDetails(self):
        print 'Details for the Tribe are: '
        print '\t Tribe:', self.tribe 
        print '\t Coordinates: ', self.coordinates
```

And you have a bunch of villages as in:

```
In [10]: vs = [new_village() for i in range(3)]

In [11]: for v in vs: print v.getTribe(), v.getCoords()
teutons [8, 6]
gauls [6, 9]
teutons [1, 8]
```

Then, you can always get villages which correspond to a particular coordinate:

```
In [14]: map(lambda v: v.printDetails() , filter(lambda v: v.getCoords() == [8,6]  , vs))
Details for the Tribe are:
         Tribe: teutons
         Coordinates:  [8, 6]
Out[14]: [None]
```

and if the village isn't present:

```
In [15]: map(lambda v: v.printDetails() , filter(lambda v: v.getCoords() == [2,3]  , vs))
Out[15]: []
```

Note that the way the code is structured, there may be multiple villages which can be generated at the same coordinate. That ca be easily handled with a prudential `if` statement.

Comment: Don't use map and filter to find the villages by coordinate; that does an O(N) search every time, which could get long if you have a lot of villages. Instead, use the dictionary idea from timgeb's answer, where the keys of the dictionary are coordinates (in the form of (x,y) tuples) and the values of the dictionary are the village objects. It costs O(N) time to build the dictionary, but you'll only have to do it once, then lookups are O(1) time (constant time).

Comment: @rmunn - Agree with the dictionary approach.  Though I get what ssm is doing with `map` and `filter`, the complexity is worse than using a dictionary.

Comment: Oh thanks! Dictioanries are actually a good idea for searches. The only reason to use a filter is because there might be more than one village at the same location because of *my* logic. If that isn't there, it should be much easier to just have a function which returns a single village, or `None`

Comment: If it's legal to have multiple villages at the same coordinate, a dict would still be better for lookups; instead of (coordinate) -> (village object), the dict would be (coordinate) -> (list of village objects). Then when you look up "what's at location X,Y?" in your dict, you iterate over the results to get all your villages. But since the OP is building a game, I think it's likely he wants no two villages to share the same coordinates, so this is kind of a moot point.